# Latex generated pdf unreadable

Tags: latex, pdf-generation

Of late, I have observed that pdf generated by latex files are unreadable in certain email browsers (when previewing the attachment in Outlook) as well as the printed hard copy especially math symbols like inner products, integral etc overlap with each other making the file ugly and unreadable. Surprisingly the same file looks perfectly fine when viewed using the ShareLatex built-in pdf browser as well as the desktop version of Adobe Reader.

ShareLatex documentation suggest switching the PDF viewer from built-in to native. Upon changing to native, even the browser version had unreadable characters.
[https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Kb/Changing_PDF_viewer]

So, I would like to know if there is better way to compile the tex file in Sharelatex so that its readable across platforms and in print.

Most of the "pdf generation from tex" related issues posted on StackOverflow point out problems with viewing images. As such the pdf files I am generating don't contain any images.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's not a single build-in PDF viewer (browser, e-mail client, ...) that works well. But what you could test is if `\usepackage{lmodern}` makes things better ...

Comment: this should have been a comment